# How change the subdomain DNS to one different than domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, hosting, cname, a-records

I have a website hosted with nexcess and the domain with GoDaddy. I created a subdomain (test.example.com) and It must be on a different DNS than example.com (For example: ns.rackspace.com DNS).

Is possible to do that? How can I do?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting service should have given you an IP address. That IP address needs to be added the domain configuration with Godaddy.

You should be able to do a lookup of your name, test.example.com, and it should return the IP address of your server. If that doesn't happen, then the DNS configuration at Godaddy is not yet correct.